# Any existing Apache Wicket framework sample?

Tags: java, wicket

I plan to use [Wicket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket) to build a web site with database storage. I haven't used Wicket before. Is there any sample framework I can start from?

Answer (score 5):

Well the [Wicket site has more examples](http://wicket.apache.org/examples.html) than you can shake a widget at.

Remember that Wicket is just a user-interface framework, it has nothing to say about things like database access. You'll need to look elsewhere for that (JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering deploying to Google App Engine, I am working on a template project for Wicket applications.  Visit http://code.google.com/p/wicket-gae-template/ and checkout from the Subversion trunk.  It's a re-implementation of the App Engine "Guestbook" demo project, using Wicket rather than JSP.  It also uses Maven for the build, JDO for persistence, Google Guice for dependency injection, and classes to support easy unit testing.  Documentation on the site is nonexistent right now, so let the source code be your guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [my simple CRUD example with wicket, db4o and guice](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/crud-with-wicket-guice-db4o-neodatis/). But keep in mind as skaffman pointed out: "Remember that Wicket is just a user-interface framework" (wicket is a nice one!)

Nevertheless in my post I listed some projects which can be helpful if you want to use wicket with a persistence solution:

- wicketopia
- databinder
- wicketrad
- Wicket-Iolite
- antilia
- wicket-phonebook
- pure hibernate
- wicket-grails plugin

If you would like to use guice or spring with wicket then probably [these archetypes](http://jweekend.com/dev/LegUp) could help you to get started.

If you like building fancy apps take a look at [this page](http://www.wiquery.org/wiquery-examples-1.0/).